# Understanding the technical (Docker) container architecture

Tags: linux, docker, architecture, containers, busybox

I am new to containers and would like to get a good knowledge about how container technology (Docker) is made up from 'scratch'. I have to write a paper and hope that I have every important thing correctly understood so far.

The following diagram is made by me and shows my current understanding of containers.

[image]

Obviously we need an OS with a Kernel that allows us to use the hardware. For Docker this is Linux. Docker for Windows uses a VM with Linux for that.

On top of our Linux OS we then run our Docker Engine. Our Docker Engine is in charge of starting, building, configuring ... our images and containers. But most importantly the Docker Engine handles everything that has to do with isolating of containers, for example it maintains how namespaces or cgroups are used so that every container has it's own full filesystem.

Then we have our actual containers. Containers themselvesneed almost every time a kind of OS itself. This is mostly just a very compact one like Alpine or Busybox. They collect a small number of standard functions such as 'file', 'tar', 'grep' that most software definitely need. This compact OS is now using the Kernel from our full Linux OS. **They don't have their own Kernel.**

On top of the compact OS we then place our actual piece of software such as Node.js or a NGINX Server. This software is only using the compact OS which in return uses the Kernel from our full Linux OS. And all data or modifications that is generated or done in runtime are made on the writeable layer of our container.

---

And if I understood correctly, our container or everything that runs in our container is not using or interacting with our full Linux OS but just with it's Kernel?
I also don't quite understand how the writeable layer in a container works. Like how does my software for example know that a modified file from a read-only layer is now present in the writeable layer and should use this?

I would really appreciate some corrections or suggestions on what I have missed out so far. Thank you

Comment: If you want to understand the docker arch in simple words, Its a client-server architecture like our other web applications. docker cli is a client and docker-machine is a server.

Comment: For the writable layer, read the documentation on Docker Volumes - https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: not using or interacting with our full Linux OS but just with it's Kernel? -> it shares several things and runs **ONE** kernel , in fact it can interact with the host sys, either via network , or even directly with the docker socket when used as volume ... 

You should read about **privileged** mode for using e.g. tun devices , and since the UNIX/Linux way is 'everything is a file',(e.g.  "devices" are files , sockets can be files  , hard disks are files ) applies here too .. you can just "mount" it a volume

Answer (score 3):

> And if I understood correctly, our container or everything that runs in our container is not using or interacting with our full Linux OS but just with it's Kernel?

The containers are just processes. For kernel, Docker daemon, NodeJS application and Nginx are processes. That's why containers don't have their own kernels. The difference between Docker daemon process (and other processes on a host) and processes that are running within containers is in their scope (it's called a namespace). Processes in containers are run in isolation and they don't see anything around their namespace. There are many different namespaces, for example, a pid namespace is one of them and it limits the visibility of other processes. That's why ps command in a container doesn't show processes from a host or other containers. Namespaces is a kernel things and they are more about what a process can see and access to while there is also cgroups that apply limits for CPU and memory usage.

I hope this helps you somehow, at least, I tried to put more attention to the kernel because Docker is just a daemon that spins new processes with configured namespaces, cgroups and own filesystem.

Here are some links that might be useful:

- [What even is a container: namespaces and cgroups](https://jvns.ca/blog/2016/10/10/what-even-is-a-container/)
- [How containers work: overlayfs](https://jvns.ca/blog/2019/11/18/how-containers-work--overlayfs/)
- See also other posts about containers on https://jvns.ca (I recommend it because Julia explains it in simple words and even provide illustrations.)

If you want to go deeper, I'd suggest to look at [Namespaces: from chroot() to containers](https://k1024.org/papers/namespaces.html) slides and read [the article about creation of own containers](http://cesarvr.github.io/post/2018-05-22-create-containers/).

Comment: thank you for your detailed explanation and links very useful :)